What is the best way to monitor all token balances of wallet address?
Context
I'm developing a personal project to monitor token balances of all wallet addresses in my service . I can monitor token balances of several addresses by multicall. I designed my workflow of balance scanning something like this:

Cron-job every 24 hours to fetch all new token balances of all wallet addresses
If anyone requests to get balances, I will get it from redis || database -> cache in redis expire 30m and return.
Cron-job every 30m, to fetch all new token balances of all requested addresses recently

Problem
What problem I am facing is: the EVM RPC URL blocked me. Of course I'm using free endpoints, and I intend to upgrade to the payment plan. But does my workflow cost too many requests? I expect to serve ~ 200.000 wallet addresses, with ~ 5000 token addresses on 5 chains.
My questions
What is the best way to monitor token balances?

Scan every single tx, get tracing data of it and analyze by back-side code?
Scan by cronjob like above?
Use 3rd party API?

Which ways to save cost and fast return?

I am also trying to make something similar, as i wanted to try out something in the blockchain world so i am trying to make project like assestDash so i guess we are working on the same problem of fetching token balances of different addresses ,
what my approach is to connect user wallet to my application and then get the account addresses(mainly using metamask),
then use the Alchemy's API to fetch all the token balances for each address.
please correct me if I am wrong , I am new to this and just trying what all can work :)

If I understand your query properly, you want to show balance of multiple Tokens in individual wallet address. If this is your question then as a solution you can use Ether-scan or other blockchain API's or we can do this using web3 JS or Ether JS.
If it is not your query then explain more.

I want to show a wallet address's net worth as fast as when it logins into my service. 3rd party API can be a good solution, but because I want to save the cost and keep the balance mostly real-time (delay ~ 10ph). So I'm finding another solution to update the balance and handle it with my database.
